# Spell-checker in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, cs50

I've been trying to implement a spell-checker using a large dictionary against some text file which contains around 2000 words. However, my spell-checker returns all words as being misspelled. I honestly have no idea why — could someone help me?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

#define lenght 45
#define hashtable_size 65536

char word[lenght+1];
int count = 0;

/*
*
* Hash function. Thanks to Brenda from cs50 reddit.
*/
int hash_it(const char* needs_hashing)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(needs_hashing); i<n; i++)
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ needs_hashing[i];
    return hash % hashtable_size;
}

typedef struct node
{
    char* word;
    struct node* next;
}node;

node* previous;
node* hashtable[hashtable_size];


/*
*
* Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
*/
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    char word[lenght+1];
    FILE* dict = fopen(dictionary,"r");

    for(int i = 0; i < 26;i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
        for(int a = fgetc(dict); a != EOF; a = fgetc(dict))
        {
            count++;

            int hashvalue = hash_it(word);

            node* new = malloc(sizeof(node));

            if(hashtable[hashvalue] == NULL)
            {
                hashtable[hashvalue] = new;
                new -> next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                new -> next = hashtable[hashvalue];
                hashtable[hashvalue] = new;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}

/*
*
* Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
*/
bool check(const char* word)
{

    char tmp[lenght + 1];
    int lenghtw = strlen(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < lenghtw; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }


    int index = hash_it(tmp);

    if (hashtable[index] == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    node* cursor = hashtable[index];

    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(tmp, cursor -> word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor -> next;
    }

    return false;
}

/*
*
* Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
*/
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return count;
}

/*
*
* Unloads dictionary from memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
*/
bool unload(void)
{
    int index = 0;

    while(index < hashtable_size)
    {
        if(hashtable[index] == NULL)
        {
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            while(hashtable[index] != NULL)
            {
                node* cursor = hashtable[index];
                hashtable[index] = cursor -> next;
                free(cursor);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc != 2)
        return 3;

    if (!load("dictionary"))
        return 1;

    printf("loaded %d words\n", size());
    printf("word '%s'%s found\n", argv[1], check(argv[1]) ? "" : " not");
    unload();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, a `main` function which shows how you are setting up the dictionary, how you are calling the `check` and what the input file contains.

Comment: I formatted the code, and noticed there is no `main()` function.

Comment: Given the answers thus far, it is clear that you would do better to step this code in a debugger and observe the variable state and code flow than to ask SO to debug it for you,  Using a debugger is always a more efficient method of debugging than posting code and questions.  If you have never used one, the hour you take to learn the basics (less if you are not stuck with just the GDB command line debugger, and probably  less again if you are using Visual Studio) will save you many many hours of development time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

- in the `load` function, you do not load words from the dictionary into the hash table.  You read one character at a time with `fgetc()` and create a node from an uninitialized local buffer `word`.
- the `hash_it` function only hashes the last 16 characters from the word.  Furthermore, `hashtable_size` is a power of 2, a bad idea.  Indeed only the last 8 characters participate in the hash value. This is not a bug, just an inefficient hashing method.
- in the `check` function, you copy the word and convert it to lowercase, but you forget to set the final byte of the `tmp` array to `'\0'`.

Here is a corrected version of `load` that reads one word per dictionary line:

```
bool load(const char *dictionary) {
    char line[256];
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (!dict)
        return false;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, dict) != NULL) {
        char *p = line + strspn(line, " \t");  // skip blanks

        p[strcspn(p, " \t\r\n")] = '\0'; // strip trailing blanks

        if (*p == '\0' || *p == '#' || *p == ';')
            continue;  // ignore blank lines and comments

        count++;

        int hashvalue = hash_it(p);
        node *np = malloc(sizeof(node));

        np->word = strdup(p);
        np->next = hashtable[hashvalue];
        hashtable[hashvalue] = np;
    }
    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, you may remove the line declaration you do not use, and maybe stress the fact that the buffer allocated by `strdup()` needs to be freed.
 Some check of `hashtable[hashvalue]` being NULL before you put the node inside would probably prevent strange behavior in case of collision

Comment: @OznOg: Thank you for pointing out the inconsistency.  The global array `word` is actually not used.  At startup, all entries in the global array `hashtable[]` are initialized to `NULL`, so there is no need for extra checks.  If the slot is empty, `np->next` receives `NULL`, otherwise `np` is prepended to the list.

Comment: the check was about collisions in the hash which will fail silently if I understand correctly

Comment: @OznOg: Not at all, the check was redundant. The hashtable is an array of slots, each with a list of nodes that have the same hashvalue.  The code above inserts the node in the proper slot, at the beginning of the list.

Comment: Thank you ! You helped me a great deal. I'll spend time reviewing and understanding the code before implementing it.

Comment: Moreover, I'll think about a more efficient hash function.